# Create drop down list options from enum in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, .net-2.0

I currently have a class and I'm trying to create an easy GUI to create a collection of this class. Most of the attributes of this class are strings. However, one of the attributes I want the user to be able to set is an Enum.  Therefore, I would like the user interface, to have a dropdownlist for this enum, to restrict the user from entering a value that is not valid. Currently, I am taking the initial list of objects, adding them to a DataTable and setting the DataSource of my DataGridView to the table.  Works nicely, even creates a checkbox column for the one Boolean property. But, I don't know how to make the column for the enum into a dropdownlist. I am using C# and .NET 2.0.

Also, I have tried assigning the DataSource of the DataGridView to the list of my objects, but when I do this, it doesn't help with the enum and I'm unable to create new rows in the DataGridView, but I am definitely not bound to using a DataTable as my DataSource, it was simply the option I have semi-working.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I do not know if that would work with a DataGridView column but it works with ComboBoxes:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
```

and:

```
MyEnum value = (MyEnum)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

UPDATE: It works with DataGridView columns too, just remember to set the value type.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
col.Name = "My Enum Column";
col.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
col.ValueType = typeof(MyEnum);
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
```

Comment: How/Where to get access to comboBox1?

Answer (score 3):

Or, if you need to do some filtering of the enumerator values, you can loop through `Enum.GetValues(typeof(EnumeratorName))` and add the ones you want using:

```
dataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items.Add(EnumeratorValue)
```

As an aside, rather than using a DataTable, you can set the DataSource of the DataGridView to a BindingSource object, with the DataSource of the BindingSource object set to a `BindingList<Your Class>`, which you populate by passing an `IList` into the constructor.

Actually, I'd be interested to know from anyone if this is preferable to using a DataTable in situations where you don't already have one (i.e. it is returned from a database call).