# Difference between Enum.GetValues and Enum.GetNames

Tags: c#, .net

I see the `Enum.GetValues` returns base `Array` type and `Enum.GetNames` returns a `string` array. But I don't understand how this is very significant. For an `enum` anyways, the values are strings.

But, there is an associated problem. The `DataGridView` `ComboBox` column databinds to an `enum` if I give the `DataSource` = `Enum.GetValues`, but it doesn't databind when I give  it `Enum.GetNames` as a `DataSource`.

Comment: Remember `Enum.GetValues` returns duplicate values if your enum has different names of the same value. `Enum.GetNames` should give you the distinct enum names.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) will return an Array of the underlying integer values for each item in the Enum.

[GetNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx) will return a string array of the Names for the items in the enum.

The Array returned by GetValues implements IList while the string[] returned by GetNames does not, which explains the binding differences.

Answer (score 17):

Enums are actually numeric. `GetNames` returns the field names. `GetValues` returns the numeric values.

MSDN has a great sample on [`GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx).

Comment: This answer is false. GetValues returns the **Enum** values, which could be cast to numeric values (such as the integers in your example), or could be converted to strings or something else.

Comment: GetValues, in a current example where the Enum is based on long, and a value is Uin32.MaxValue + 2, then it is returned as 1 (meaning get 64 bit underlaying value is truncated to 32 bit)

Answer (score 15):

Think of enumerations as Name/Value pairs.

```
enum SignMagnitude { Negative = -1, Zero = 0, Positive = 1 };
```

In the example above, `GetNames()` will return a `string` array containing the items "Negative", "Zero", and "Positive."  `GetValues()` will return an array of `SignMagnitude` containing `SignMagnitude.Negative`, `SignMagnitude.Zero` and `SignMagnitude.One`.

---

There is an example of binding Enum names to a dropdown in a DataGridView here: [Create drop down list options from enum in a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443/create-drop-down-list-options-from-enum-in-a-datagridview)