# Print constants contained in an Enum

Tags: c#, enums

```
public struct RollerCoasterInfo
{
    public string Name;
    public RollerCoasterType Type;
}

public enum RollerCoasterType
{
    Wooden,
    Steel,
    Hyper,
    Heartline,
    VirginiaReel,
    Mine,
    Suspeneded,
}
class RollerCoasterProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RollerCoasterInfo rc1;
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Following Information");
        Console.Write("Name of the Rollercoaster: ");
        rc1.Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Type of rollecoaster {0} is", rc1.Name);
        ...
    }
}
```

How would I print all the constants in the enum Rollercoastertype so it looks like the example below?

> 1. Wooden
> 2. Steel
> 3. Hyper
> 4. ETC...

Comment: Use the [`Enum.GetNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
   //All enums
    var x = Enum.GetValues(typeof(RollerCoasterType));
    foreach(var item in x)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}",(int)item,item);
    
    //Just names
    var names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(RollerCoasterType));       
    foreach(var name in names)
        Console.WriteLine(name);
```

See it working in my fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/AIGl6M

> **Note:**
>
> - `Enum.GetValues`: Will get all values from enum for example `Enum.GetValues(typeof(RollerCoasterType))` will returns an array `RollerCoasterType[]`;
>
> > - `Enum.GetNames`: Will get all values name from enum for example `Enum.getNames(typeof(RollerCoasterType))` will returns an array `string[]`;

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanks.  I'm assuming {0} returns the value of the name and {1}  returns the name?   And why does that work that way?

Comment: @Warlord213 it get the 0 based order of the parameters after the string, like `string.Format(string str, params string[] args)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(RollerCoasterType), 3))
```

'3' here is the element index.

Answer (score 0):

another way would be:

```
var _values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Rollercoastertype )).Cast<Rollercoastertype >();
```

Here's a link which shows the difference between all these answers: Enum.GetValue vs. Enum.GetName: [Difference between Enum.GetValues and Enum.GetNames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282947/difference-between-enum-getvalues-and-enum-getnames)