# C# enum exercise mycolor - print color and it's int (list index)

Tags: c#, enumeration

I'm trying to solve this question, and I need your help.

I use enumeration of the colors. The code below prints each color's name. My question is how do I add each color index number as well?

```
foreach (string i in Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyColors)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

public enum MyColors
{
        White = 0,
        Black = 1,
        Orange = 2,
        Purple = 4,
}
```

Comment: Add use of Enum.GetValues() as decribed in this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282947/difference-between-enum-getvalues-and-enum-getnames

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get int value from enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943398/get-int-value-from-enum)

Comment: Thank you Arnaud,

I am sorry , I am preaty new with C#, I read the links you've attached, I am little lost. 
I don't know what should I add in order to add the enum index value for each color.

I do get each color by using "GetValues" , now i need to add also GetValue to get the index.

how do i "merge" these 2 functionalities ?

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not think that is a particularly well posed question I'll try and answer your question.

You can get the actual values (not only the *names*) with `Enum.GetValues(Type enumType)`. These values can be casted to integers to output the numbers

```
foreach (var enumValue in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyColors)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", (int)enumValue, enumValue);
}
```