# Bad enum field value in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I am creating a little ASP.NET app and have a problem with one field value.

I have defined my enum in a class:

```
class Column
{
    public enum Type {
    Undefined = 0,
    Integer = 1,
    ShortDate = 2,
    Etc = 3 }

    // some other stuff
}
```

The app contains some controls to enter properties of a column, namely a dropdownlist for choosing the column type and some unimportant others. And when all properties are properly entered, SaveButton in enabled to save the column type info into a listbox. My Default.aspx.cs contains:

```
private Column.Type selectedType;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // fill the ColumnTypeDropDownList (from the Column.Type enum)
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (Column.Type ct in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Column.Type)))
        {
            ColumnTypeDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(ct.ToString()));
        }
    }
}

protected void ColumnTypeDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrepareToSave();
}

// also called from other controls events, therefore in a separate method
private void PrepareToSave()
{
    // control if all needed properties are entered and set the field
    if ((ColumnNameTextBox.Text != "") && (ColumnTypeDropDownList.SelectedValue != Column.Type.Undefined.ToString()))
    {
        foreach (Column.Type ct in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Column.Type)))
        {
            if (ct.ToString() == ColumnTypeDropDownList.SelectedValue) selectedType = ct;
        }
        SaveButton.Enabled = true;
    }
}

protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ColumnsListBox.Items.Add(selectedType.ToString());    // always writes "Undefined"
}
```

The problem is that it always writes "Undefined" into the listbox, even though another type was selected from the dropdownlist. I tried to add the item into the listbox inside the PrepareToSave() method and that works correctly, but I need it outside. On the other hand, the condition controlling if any other value than Undefined is selected from the dropdownlist works well. It seems that the field selectedType has the correct selected value only inside the PrepareToSave() method.

AutoPostBack of all the controls is enabled.

Am I missing something about the enums or do you have any tips how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't the field's value get reinitialised every time a PostBack call is made?

Comment: Your selectedType property is not persitent. Every time you change the dropdown index a postback will be made. This means that your local variable will be created at every postback. You should set the `AutoPostback=false` on your dropdown and handle the enable/disable logic of your button via JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the line...

```
ColumnTypeDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(ct.ToString()));
```

..namely in `new ListItem(ct.ToString())`. When you use [this constructor of the `ListItem` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s45c347s(v=vs.110).aspx), you create an item with `Value` set to `null`. Later you compare against the value:

```
if (ct.ToString() == ColumnTypeDropDownList.SelectedValue) selectedType = ct;
```

Since `Value` of each of the items is `null`, `ColumnTypeDropDownList.SelectedValue` is also `null` and your comparison fails. That should be also easily figured out in a debugger.

The correct list item constructor for you is

```
ListItem listItem = new ListItem(ct.ToString(), ct.ToString());
```

As an additional issue, you have to call `PrepareToSave` in `SaveButton_Click`, since the `selectedType` field will have lost its value across requests. `PrepareToSave` will rebuild that value.

Comment: Your last paragraph was the key. Now it works. Then I also moved the foreach cycle directly to the save handler and let `PrepareToSave` only enable the button, so the code is cleaner. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That's most probably because of your `if` condition as pointed below

```
if ((ColumnNameTextBox.Text != "") && (ColumnTypeDropDownList.SelectedValue != Column.Type.Undefined.ToString()))
{
```

Instead of `ColumnNameTextBox.Text != ""` use `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ColumnNameTextBox.Text)`

Answer (score 0):

Just another tip:

Use [`GetNames` instead of `GetValues`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8282947/difference-between-enum-getvalues-and-enum-getnames) in your `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (var ct in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Column.Type)))
{
    //do your stuff.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use AutoPostBack ...

Add a hidden control to your page.
In your `PrepareToSave();` method you just can add the *selectetType* like `yourControlName.Text = ct;`

And change your save handler to this ....

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Read the value of the hidden control
    ColumnsListBox.Items.Add(yourControlName.Text);   
}
```