# DataGridView: ComboBox Column using Enum. A way to setup from designer?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have one column in a `DataGridView` and would like it to be a `ComboBox` cell displaying the possible values for the `enum`:

```
public enum SurfaceType {Rough, Smooth, Mirror};
```

I looked around and found articles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443/create-drop-down-list-options-from-enum-in-a-datagridview) which is the result I would like but I was just wondering if there was a way to set this up from the "Designer" mode of adding the columns. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple data type and make the ctor private. it will be easier to work with

```
public class SurfaceType
{
    public static SurfaceType Rough  = new SurfaceType{Id=1, Description="Rough"};
    public static SurfaceType Smooth  = new SurfaceType{Id=2, Description="Smooth"};
    public static SurfaceType Mirror  = new SurfaceType{Id=3, Description="Mirror"};

    private SurfaceType()
    {
    }

    public int Id {get private set;}
    public string Description {get private set;}

    //override equality and hashcode is necessary.
}
```

the other nice thing about this approach is you can then encapsulate functions within the SurfaceType object itself.

Comment: I think the OP is asking if you can set up the databinding from the Windows Forms Designer, which this answer does not address.

Comment: sure you can with some helper methods to convert the enum to a value and text, but it's more trouble than its worth. this provides an alternative to enums. and still provides the same logical functionality. @buck response does just this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the designer to add a dropdown to a template and bind the dropdown to a business object data source.  However, you'd need a bit of code to wrap the enum.  Something like this in a helper class works.

```
public static DataSet GetEnums()
{
    DataSet data = new DataSet();
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("Name");
    table.Columns.Add("ID");
    data.Tables.Add(table);

    DataRow r;

    foreach (SurfaceType st in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SurfaceType)))
    {   
        r = data.Tables[0].NewRow();
        r["Name"] = st.ToString();
        r["ID"] = (int)st;
        data.Tables[0].Rows.Add(r);
    }
    return data;
}
```