# DataGridView Default Error on ComboBox Column

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, datagridview, enums, .net-4.5

I have a DataGridView in my .NET 4.5 WinForms app with two columns. One column is a regular textbox column and the other column is a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` that is a dropdown. I am trying to bind the columns to a `BindingList` of my `Filter` object and I would like everything inside of the enum `FilterType` to show up in the dropdown. Here's the code for my object and enum:

```
public class Filter
{
  public string keyword { get; set; }
  public FilterType type { get; set; }
}

public enum FilterType : int   //the strings should appear in the dropdown
{
  SESSION = 1,
  ORDER = 2,
  SHIPMENT = 3
}
```

I have manually created the columns in the VS 2012 designer where I changed the `ColumnType`, `HeaderText`, and `DataPropertyName` to `keyword` and `type`.
Using an answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56483/1689089) I have added these two lines of code to my form loading event:

```
colFilterType.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FilterType));
colFilterType.ValueType = typeof(FilterType);
```

When I run the code I initially see a blank row. Whenever I click on the row, irregardless of which column is clicked, I get a pop-up error.

> System.ArgumentException: DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid. ... please handle the DataError event.

I can ignore it and type whatever text I want into the `Keyword` column, and the dropdown is magically filled in with the first value of the enum. However, if I even mouse-over the dropdown the error pops up again (please see the screenshot). I am not sure what causes the error and don't know where to set a breakpoint. I also do not know if I'm creating the problem by making parts of the DataGridView in the designer and modifying those in code. The designer does not let me set the `DataSource` the way I did in the code. It also contains a field `ValueMember` that I haven't seen used in code.

[image]

Although not ideal, I wouldn't mind catching the error and doing nothing with it since the dropdown seems to populate itself (and assuming all the data stays intact).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine when adding the column at runtime. Sample code:

```
 DataGridViewComboBoxColumn colFilterType = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
 colFilterType.HeaderText = "Name you want";
 colFilterType.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FilterType));
 colFilterType.ValueType = typeof(FilterType);
 dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colFilterType);
```

Errors like the one you report are usually provoked while changing the type of a cell/column at runtime, because of the big number of events which are triggered every time a `DataGridView` is affected in any way: some of them expect the old type and find elements with the new one (e.g., expecting an `int` and finding a `string`).

Comment: This works, and thanks for the tip! However, whenever a new row is added the new dropdown is blank. I then need to click on the dropdown once to give it focus, another time to populate it, and once more to finally open it. Is this another quirk of the `DataGridView` or do you know if can I fix this somehow?

Comment: @valsidalv You are welcome. The new row is blank because it does not select any item by default; just change that by forcing the selected item to be the one you want.

Comment: I actually discovered an issue. The field `colFilterType.DataPropertyName` must be set to `"type"` in order for the changes in the DataGridView to be correctly updated in the bound List of `Filter`s, otherwise they all show up as `0`. Adding this binding brings up the error.

Comment: @valsidalv You should understand that I cannot guess what you have in your code. If you create a new DataGridView, with no columns, and execute the code in my answer it would work fine without doing anything else. Your error (the one you complained about) is provoked by changing the type of the given column (you are setting a different type in Design View). Any other problem you can find would be provoked by your code. If you don't share it I wouldn't be able to help. Although you shouldn't say that it triggers an error otherwise, because it is not true.

Comment: @valsidalv Also, in the future, if you don't mind, please, try to avoid the mark in/out issue, which I personally don't like too much. The mark tells which answer solves the problem; so wait until your problem is solved or ask as much as required (I understood that your code was working fine already but well...). I invite you to take a look at my profile to understand my opinion regarding this and similar issues.

Comment: The `DataSource` of my GridView is set to a `BindingList<Filter>`, so any changes made in the GridView should be reflected in the list - this is accomplished by setting the `DataPropertyName` of the column to the appropriate variable name within `Filter`. It works correctly for the Keyword field, but not Filter Type. This isn't what my question asked, so thanks for your help :) but perhaps I will rephrase it and ask a new one.

Comment: @valsidalv the code in your question didn't refer that, but .DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FilterType));, what my answer has been about. Logically, you have to set the right DataSource; if you use a different method you have to add different properties. But what has this to do with the original error and with my answer (where I haven't included a BindlingList at all?!)?. Do you know this thing of one question per post, don't you? Please, I insist in you taking a look at my profile, such that we both are synchronised regarding what should expect from each other. MISUSERS sub-section :)

Comment: @valsidalv I have updated my answer to reflect this issue you discovered; I am sure that future readers will find this pretty useful.

Comment: Well I was going to accept your answer again because I realize you did indeed answer my *question*, it isn't your fault that it didn't solve my *problem*. I unmarked it in haste, thinking that someone else would offer a solution but the better conclusion is to post a new question.

Comment: @valsidalv You are free to mark any answer. But I am also free to express by opinion and I don't think that your behaviour is what SO expects (solutions working for future readers); if you want to ask about any issue, update your question but how can you expect someone to answer something which wasn't even asked? If you are not sure, take all the time you need to mark the right answer and to ask as much as required; but please try to make this whole process relevant to others (share the code you are complaining about).